# how to solve error: module not found after running Node.js for express app

Tags: node.js, express

I am creating my first express app and when I run `node index.js` to get it up and running, I am getting the following error:

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:800
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '/Users/heathergarcia/technical-assessment/index.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:797:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:690:27)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1047:10)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:11 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
```

When I run `pwd` in my command line the file path matches the file path above so I am not sure why it is not finding the module. I have tried running `npm install` and that did not work. Here is my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "technical-assessment",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "license": "ISC",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "request": "^2.88.0"
  }
}
```

Project Structure:

```
*Test Project
 --- JS folder
   -- index.js
 --- node_modules folder
   -- with many folders and files
 --- src folder 
   -- views folder
     - index.html
 --- styles folder
  -- index.css

package-lock.json and package.json files
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: can you shear your project structure?

Comment: @DanStarns thanks!

TestApp 

--- JS folder
  --index.js 

--- node_modules folder
  --with many folders and files

--- src folder
  --views folder 
    - index.html

---styles
  
Then package-lock.json and package.json files

Comment: @DanStarns I added the structure to my question so it's easier to read.

Comment: According to your project structure, It should be `node JS\ folder/index.js`

Comment: Thank you!! Removing the JS file worked for me!